# C Programming: Check if the IP address is added on any given NIC

Tags: c, linux, ip

Problem description:
I have a IP address (can be either IPv4/IPv6) and NIC address,  how can I check if the IP address is added to the given NIC(or any NIC) using C.

I know it is simple to do the same on command line/using scripts, however I need to check the same in C Program.

Example:
IP - 192.168.0.1
NIC - eth0

Using command line(linux platform) the below command would tell me if the IP is added or not:

```
ip addr show | grep "192.168.0.1"
```

p.s.: Is there any library function which can be used to get similar outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method(GETIFADDRS) suggested above is correct solution for the stated problem description. The getifaddrs browses through all the IP's on the NIC.

However in my case there are many IP's addresses added on the NIC/system and I am OK with knowing if the IP is present in any of the NIC. I found a easier/faster solution.

To check if the IP is added on any of the NIC card of the machine, just open a TCP socket and bind with port=zero(0) and the IP address to be checked. The successful bind will suggest that the IP is available/present.

*Note: This works if IP is added on any of the NIC card in the system. The port zero should be used instead of hard-coding as it selects any available port on in the system*
(ref. http://compnetworking.about.com/od/tcpip/p/port-numbers-0.htm)

This method is tested for both IPv4/IPv6 in UNIX environment(rhel)

PS:Do not forget to close the socket after verifying the presence of IP

Comment: Unfortunately, the bind() method does not work, if

    /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_binnd=1

That is, sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind is 1

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `getifaddrs`, which returns a list of network interfaces and the addresses associated with them.

From the man page:

```
int getifaddrs(struct ifaddrs **ifap);
```

> The  `getifaddrs()` function creates a linked list of structures
>   describing the network interfaces of the local system, and stores
>   the  address    of  the  first item of the list in `*ifap`.  The list
>   consists of `ifaddrs`    structures, defined as follows:

```
       struct ifaddrs {
           struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;    /* Next item in list */
           char            *ifa_name;    /* Name of interface */
           unsigned int     ifa_flags;   /* Flags from SIOCGIFFLAGS */
           struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;    /* Address of interface */
           struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask; /* Netmask of interface */
           union {
               struct sockaddr *ifu_broadaddr;
                                /* Broadcast address of interface */
               struct sockaddr *ifu_dstaddr;
                                /* Point-to-point destination address */
           } ifa_ifu;
       #define              ifa_broadaddr ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr
       #define              ifa_dstaddr   ifa_ifu.ifu_dstaddr
           void            *ifa_data;    /* Address-specific data */
       };
```

Here's an example of how I've used it in one of my programs:

```
union sockaddr_u {
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6;
};

struct iflist {
    char name[IFNAME_LEN];
    union sockaddr_u su;
    int isloopback;
    int ismulti;
    int ifidx;
};

void getiflist(struct iflist *list, int *len)
{
    struct ifaddrs *ifa, *ifa_tmp;
    int count;
    unsigned ifidx;

    if (getifaddrs(&ifa) == -1) {
        perror("getifaddrs failed");
        *len = 0;
        return;
    }
    ifa_tmp = ifa;
    count = *len;
    *len = 0;
    while (ifa_tmp && (*len < count)) {
        if ((ifidx = if_nametoindex(ifa_tmp->ifa_name)) == 0) {
            perror("Error getting interface index for interface %s",
                              ifa_tmp->ifa_name);
            continue;
        }
        if (ifa_tmp->ifa_addr && ((ifa_tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) ||
                                  (ifa_tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6)) &&
                    ((ifa_tmp->ifa_flags & IFF_UP) != 0)) {
            memset(&list[*len], 0, sizeof(struct iflist));
            strncpy(list[*len].name, ifa_tmp->ifa_name,
                    sizeof(list[*len].name) - 1);
            memcpy(&list[*len].su, ifa_tmp->ifa_addr,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
            list[*len].isloopback = (ifa_tmp->ifa_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK) != 0;
            list[*len].ismulti = (ifa_tmp->ifa_flags & IFF_MULTICAST) != 0;
            list[*len].ifidx = ifidx;
            (*len)++;
        }
        ifa_tmp = ifa_tmp->ifa_next;
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifa);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this would do the job

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use GETIFADDRS http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html

Comment: Thanks alot, this would do the job

Answer (score 0):

This should Work:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<netdb.h>


int main(void){
    struct ifaddrs *ip, *hosst;
    int s;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];

    if (getifaddrs(&ip) == -1){
        perror("getifaddrs");
        return 1;
    }

    for (hosst = ip; hosst != NULL; hosst = hosst->ifa_next){
        if (hosst->ifa_addr == NULL){
            continue;
        }

        s=getnameinfo(hosst->ifa_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in),host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);

        if((strcmp(hosst->ifa_name,"wlan0")==0)&&(hosst->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET)){
            if (s != 0){
                printf("getnameinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
                return 1;
            }
            printf("IP  - %s\n", host);
            printf("NIC - %s\n",hosst->ifa_name );
        }
    }

    free(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> IP  - 192.168.0.110
> NIC - wlan0
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for getting IP associated with a NIC

Comment: I realized that, now I'm at work I will update my post tomorrow.